# Json response mapping with % symbol

Tags: java, json

I have JSON response like this, need to know how to parse this kind of mapping with % symbol in Java

```
{
    message = "No such entity with %fieldName = %fieldValue, %field2Name = %field2Value";
    parameters =     {
        field2Name = websiteId;
        field2Value = 1;
        fieldName = email;
        fieldValue = "a@b.com";
    };
}
```

Comment: can you tell us what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Also what have you tried so far?

Comment: I want to know that is there any library or method by which we can parse such kind of response. because I'havnt seen such responses till now.
This JSON is returned from Magento 2.0 Rest API's